# Which solutions are available for printing on the iPad to a HP LaserJet 1020 printer?

Tags: ipad, printing

I have an HP LaserJet 1020 connected to an IOGear network print server.

Currently the iPad doesn't support printing out of the box, however I have heard there are several third-party solutions on the market, each with a mixed bag of results.

Which solutions are available and which is the most versatile or successful?

Answer (score 7):

Apple has indicated printing will be available with the iOS 4.2 release, currently scheduled for November 2010.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked at this issue before for my parents.  Apparently there are many solutions that do part of the full range of (document types, printers) well.

My suggestion is this: http://mobile.eurosmartz.com/prod_index.html#comparison

I'm trying out PrintBureau. Wish they had a demo version so I could test before buying.

Answer (score 1):

[Print n share](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/print-n-share-for-documents/id301656026?mt=8) is an app I use on my iPad. I don't have an AirPrint enabled printer, but with this app, I can print via the weprint server on my Mac from the iPad. I would definitely recommend taking a look at this app. luck

Answer (score 0):

My wife and I have been using Printopia for a while now and it works perfectly for us. I have it installed on my computer and anyone with any iOS device can see it when they choose print in iOS. They then choose our HP 1022n which is connected to our AirPort Extreme base station and that's it, printing.

http://www.ecamm.com/mac/printopia/

We print from two iPad (3), an iPhone 4 and a 4S, and our friends have a variety of iOS devices of different vintages (and OS versions) and they too can print on our network.

Comment: Printopia works fine for me, but my iPhone talks via wifi to my Mac, which is physically connected to the printer.

Comment: Right GEdgar, I don't think it matters how the connection from Mac to printer is made, my bad for describing that as it sounds like it's the only way. I was just describing my setup.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Fingerprint 2 from Collobos Software. From the developers site:

> FingerPrint automatically discovers all printers connected to your Mac
>   or PC and makes them available to your iPad, iPhone, and iPod touch.
>   For a fraction of the cost of a new printer, FingerPrint breathes new
>   life into the printers you already own.

The basic premise of the software is that you install it on a PC or MAC and it acts as a simple print server proxy to provide any access to any printers connected to your computer. It offers work flow integration and security (ACL's). You must be on a WiFi connection to be able to print. I use this software daily and it "just works". It's not an inexpensive solution ($19.95) but for the money it is incredibly simple to setup and will have your printing in under 5 minutes.

Developers site: [Collobos Software](http://www.collobos.com/)